# Using Eclipse NonNull annotations with multiple Gradle projects

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, annotations

We've been using the Eclipse @NonNull and @Nullable annotations in our code for a while.
We are now adding some Spring projects defined with Gradle to our system.  These projects will share quite a bit of code with our standalone projects as well.

We are seeing a problem due the Eclipse annotations (being compile time checking) don't work when a Spring/Gradle project refers to the shared code via Gradle generated .jar file.  Eclipse needs to have the source of the shared jar in order for the annotations to work.  Attaching the source in the Eclipse project only works until you need to do a Gradle Refresh, as that rebuilds the eclipse .project and .classpath files.

It's also a problem that you have to explicitly rebuild the shared .jar each time you make a change to the shared code.  It's not done automatically.

I haven't found a way to have the Spring/Gradle projects just use a 2nd source directory for the shared code, and not need to have the shared code as a generated .jar file.

Is there any good way to have shared code between multiple Gradle projects in Eclipse - without using an intermediate .jar file?  (Or some other way to get the Eclipse annotations to work.)

Not really sure how to give a full example, as most of this is gradle and eclipse configuration.

Here are the Gradle config files: settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
            maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
            gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'App1-Account-Manager'
```

and build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-RC1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
group = 'com.efi'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.2'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'

    implementation files('lib/eflow/eFlowClientApi.jar',
    'lib/eflow/eFlowCryptography.jar',
    'lib/eflow/json-simple-1.1.1.jar',
    'lib/eflow/commons-codec-1.4.jar',
    'lib/eflow/commons-io-2.6.jar',
    'lib/eflow/commons-lang-2.6.jar',
    'lib/eflow/commons-logging-1.2.jar',
    '../App1-Commons/build/libs/App1-Commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    )

    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jdt', name: 'org.eclipse.jdt.annotation', version: '2.1.100'

    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.7'

    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

App1-Commons is the project of shared code that multiple other projects depend on.  That's where a bunch of the @NonNull annotations are.

I can set the App1-Account-Manager project to depend on the App1-Commons project in eclipse - but as soon as you run a Gradle Refresh, it looses that connection.

I'd prefer to just have the source from App1-Commons included in the App1-Account-Manager project - but I don't see how to configure Gradle to do that with Eclipse projects.

Comment: That sounds like the project dependency is done via a created artifact instead of directly referencing the project directly. Yes, the bytecode does not contain null annotation. So the source or Javadoc has to be attached. In all cases, this should be possible via Gradle.  Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution.  I need to add a SourceSets block to the build.gradle file like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir '../App1-Commons/src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

And remove the reference to the App1-Commons jar file.